# What are some undocumented iPhone features?

Tags: iphone

With included documentation as sparse as Apple's, there are plenty of them...

Comment: For reference, all useful answers from the previous Super User question [Hidden features of the iPhone](http://superuser.com/questions/5940/hidden-features-of-the-iphone) (now deleted) have been copied to this question.

Comment: A lot of these answers are documented: http://www.apple.com/iphone/tips/

Answer (score 65):

When using the keyboard, if you tap the `123` button, and slide your finger (without lifting it) to any number or punctuation symbol, when you lift your finger the keyboard will return to the alphabetic keyboard automatically. One less tap!

Comment: The same is true for the shift key; press-slide-release instead of tap-tap to get an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 42):

Really, really hidden features that will only appear if you chant the correct spells:

Dial :

> **3001#12345#* *

to bring up the spirit of iPhone's Field Test mode (*this is different from the DFU mode familair to jailbreakers*), which will give you information about towers and signal strength, 3G/EDGE network and much more info which no mortal would ever need.

[image: iPhone Field Test]

> ***#06#**

will display your IMEI. No need to tap Call.

And some spells that only works in AT&T land:

> ***777#** and tap Call. Account balance for prepaid iPhone.
>
> ***225#** and tap Call. Bill Balance. (Postpaid only)
>
> ***646#** and tap Call. Check minutes. (Postpaid only)

And a few more enchantments related to call forwarding :

> ***#21#** and tap Call. Setting interrogation for call forwards.

*Discover the settings for your call forwarding. You'll see whether you have voice, data, fax, sms, sync, async, packet access, and pad access call forwarding enabled or disabled.*

And lots and lots of other spells for all occassions, phew...

---

> ***#30#** and tap Call.

*Calling line presentation check.*

This displays whether you have enabled or disabled the presentation of the calling line, presumably the number of the party placing the call.

> ***#76#** and tap Call.

*Check whether the connected line presentation is enabled or not.*

State whether the connected line presentation is enabled or disabled. Presumably similar to the calling line presentation.

> ***#43#** and tap Call.

*Determine if call waiting is enabled.*

Displays call waiting status for voice, data, fax, sms, sync data, async data, packet access and pad access. Each item is either enabled or disabled.

> ***#61#** and tap Call.

*Check the number for unanswered calls.*

Show the number for voice call forwarding when a call is unanswered. Also show the options for data, fax, sms, sync, async, packet access and pad access.

> ***#62#** and tap Call.

*Check the number for call forwarding if no service is available.*

Just like the previous, except for no-service rather than no-answer situations.

> ***#67#** and tap Call.

*Check the number for call forwarding when the iPhone is busy.*

And again, but for when the iPhone is busy.

> ***#33#** and tap Call.

*Check for call control bars.*

Check all the usual suspects (voice, data, fax, sms, etc) to see whether barring is enabled or disabled for outgoing.

---

*originally submitted by [GeneQ](https://superuser.com/users/1021/geneq) on Super User.*

Comment: You can't access the Field Test Mode in iOS4.

Comment: You can't in 4.0. You can in 4.1 (barely meaningfully). You can in 4.2.

Comment: you also can in iOS 8.1.2

Answer (score 40):

Clicking the home button and power button will capture your screen and put it on your Photo Albums

Answer (score 27):

Scenario: You are trying to take a picture of yourself (and perhaps a friend), so you have the phone turned around, and you cant seem to hit the "shutter" button to take a picture.

Tip: Hold your finger on the "shutter" button, turn the phone around, and when you are ready to take a picture remove your finger. The picture will be taken when you remove your finger. This is much easier than the "old" approach.

Comment: Nice trick, +1. Btw: in iOS 5, you can use the volume-up-button to take a picture.

Comment: In iOS 8 and above, holding your finger on the shutter triggers burst mode, so you will need to use the volume buttons instead.

Answer (score 26):

Special characters on the keyboard.

- Hold down E, Y, U, I, O, A, S, L, Z, C, or N to bring up accented letters
- Hold down $ in the number/symbol keyboard to display other currency symbols
- Hold down “ or ‘ in the number/symbol keyboard to access alternative quote characters
- Hold down ? or ! in the number/symbol keyboard to bring up the ¿ or ¡ symbol
- Hold down the .com key when entering Web addresses to bring up options for .net, .edu and .org. (You can also do this trick when entering email addresses in Mail by tapping and holding the . (period) key.)

[image: iPhone extended keyboard]

(from http://mac.elated.com/2009/01/05/15-secret-iphone-tips-and-tricks/ )

---

*originally submitted by [Herb Caudill](https://superuser.com/users/1932/herb-caudill) on Super User.*

Comment: holding down the .com key will also display country-specific extensions for your locale e.g. .co.uk

Comment: Although it seems quicker just to type .com than wait for the hover selector to appear.

Comment: Is is only hidden for people that don't have any umlauts (americans etc.). For everybody else, this is day to day business...

Answer (score 21):

Tapping the status bar will almost always bring you to the top of the scroll view.

Comment: It's not necessarily a iPhone feature; it's more of a feature that many applications have, right?

Comment: Actually, it is built in to the standard table-view control provided by iOS, so developers don't have to do anything special to make it happen.  Thus, practically any application that has a "scrolling list" will have this feature, unless the developer really screwed up.

Comment: @Kristopher Johnson, not "table-view" but any scroll view.

Answer (score 17):

Go to Settings->General->Keyboard, and turn on Enable Caps Lock. When typing the shift key will still behave as before, but now you will have the option to double-tap it to turn on Caps-Lock (shift key will turn blue). Useful for acronyms, and shouting.

*originally submitted by [jwaddell](https://superuser.com/users/4402/jwaddell) on Super User.*

Comment: +1: I love this tip - I had my phone for almost a year before I realized it was there!

Answer (score 16):

Since the screen is multitouch, you can hold the `Shift` key while typing other keys to type them in uppercase (just like a real keyboard).

Comment: fairly obvious 'feature'

Comment: double tapping shift leaves it active to save you a bit of RSI

Answer (score 15):

Double tapping the space key ends a sentence by filling in a period.

*originally submitted by [Sathya](https://superuser.com/users/4377/sathya) on Super User.*

Comment: Also auto-capitalizes the first letter of the next sentence.

Answer (score 11):

If you hold your finger down on a link in Safari then you can open the linked page in a new "tab".

*originally submitted by [John Topley](https://superuser.com/users/1311/john-topley) on Super User.*

Answer (score 9):

You can play videos even when the phone is locked.

Sometimes I listen to video podcasts, where all I am interested in is the audio. When doing this, if you lock the phone the podcast stops playing.

However, you can start the podcast playing again even with the phone locked. Just double press the home key to bring up the iPod controls and then press play.

---

*originally submitted by [andynormancx](https://superuser.com/users/4073/andynormancx) on Super User.*

Answer (score 8):

Everyone knows about pinch to zoom in/out on Google Maps. Many people know that they can double-tap to zoom in. 
Did you know that you can do **two-finger-tap to zoom out**? So useful when driving with iPhone mounted on dash.

Comment: You mean three-finger-tap, not two-finger.

Comment: 2-finger tap on maps to zoom out. I do mean 2. 3-finger tap doesn't do anything on maps on my iPhone.

Answer (score 7):

Since the 3GS, you can use the headphones remote button to stop/start video recording

Answer (score 5):

In 3.0, you can hold down the hyphen key on the keyboard to get an em dash character. Similarly hold down the period to get an ellipsis. You can also hold down keys such as "a" or "e" to get accented versions of those letters.

*originally submitted by [John Topley](https://superuser.com/users/1311/john-topley) on Super User.*

Comment: The bonus of using this method to get your ellipsis is that it does not autocapitalize after it.  Try typing 3 periods and you get it followed by a Cap if you have autocap enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Double clicking the home button **in iOS4** shows a custom task bar with your recently used and *still running* multi-tasked apps. Click and hold to close them one by one.

Also shows the iPod controls as before.

Comment: Not on my iPhone. Double-home goes to phone favourites, or iPod controls if it's playing. Pressing home once when you're already on the home screen goes to the search page.

There is a jailbreak app that puts recent apps on the search page, I have no idea what it's called (even though I'm running it).

Comment: This is an iOS4 feature

Comment: Make that iOS4 running on a 3GS or above

Comment: It is iOS4, edited my answer to reflect - gimme back that vote ;)

Comment: Gave you mine.           <3 comment length restrictions.  <3 1 comment per 15 seconds restriction too. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

Comment: But is this feature hidden at all? This is shown in presentation videos on the apple website ...

Comment: Also, these apps aren't always 'still running', they just have their states saved in memory.

Answer (score 3):

In 3.0, you can adjust the scrubbing speed through a song by touching the scrubbing slider, then moving your finger *down* on the screen. Different distances from the scrubbing bar mean different (slower) scrubbing speeds.

While it's not exactly private browsing, you can clear your Safari history, cookies, and cache from the Settings application in the Safari menu.

The Home button (when pressed in the Springboard) by default will send you to the first screen of applications. However, if you press Home, wait for the first page of apps to be displayed, then press Home again, the Search screen will be presented. Subsequent presses will toggle back and forth between the first apps page and the Search page. (Note that you have to delay slightly between presses, otherwise the two-press shortcut will kick in and launch some other app (iPod by default)).

*originally submitted by [Tim](https://superuser.com/users/2165/tim) on Super User.*

Answer (score 3):

In 3.0, when editing some text, shake the phone to get the option undo your edits. To redo your edits, just shake the phone again.

*originally submitted by [andynormancx](https://superuser.com/users/4073/andynormancx) on Super User.*

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered that if you scroll to the top of the list of Contacts in the Phone app, your own phone number is listed above the search field.

*originally submitted by [John Topley](https://superuser.com/users/1311/john-topley) on Super User.*

Comment: Only works when accessing the Contacts through the Phone app. In the Contacts app itself, your number is not displayed.

Comment: Another reason why the contacts app is a waste of space.

Answer (score 2):

In the Mail application you can select the portion of text that you want to quote. Hit the Reply button and the selection will appear at the end of the email, instead of the whole original message.

*originally submitted by [John Topley](https://superuser.com/users/1311/john-topley) on Super User.*

Answer (score 2):

In the maps app you don't have to pinch to zoom in and out. Double tapping zooms in and tapping with two fingers zooms out.

This makes it much easier when you are using the phone with one hand.

*originally submitted by [andynormancx](https://superuser.com/users/4073/andynormancx) on Super User.*

Comment: And triple-tap to zoom out. When you use this double/triple-tap, you jump from one true scale to the next, avoiding muddy images that occur in between true scale steps.

Comment: How do you tap with two fingers using only one hand? :)

Answer (score 2):

When the iPhone is locked you can still access the iPod back/play/pause/next track buttons by pressing the Home button twice - only discovered that the other day and completely by accident...!

[image]

*originally submitted by [Mike McClelland](https://superuser.com/users/562/mike-mcclelland) on Super User.*

Comment: And if it's not currently playing, press Home *thrice* to get the same controls.

Comment: No longer works in iOS 4 on multi-tasking enabled devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can double tap the shift to keep caps lock on.
Tap just below the seek/scrub bar to hide/show it.

*originally submitted by [e11world](https://superuser.com/users/16250/e11world) on Super User.*

Comment: (Does not work on my iPod Touch 2nd Gen with iOS 4.) Sorry, it DOES work, but only if you activate scroll lock in the keyboard settings (as posted somewhere below).

Comment: Needs to be enabled in settings first.

Comment: Enable in Settings->General->Keyboard->Enable Caps Lock.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to any audio that is being streamed through Quicktime in Safari (.mp3, .m3u, .pls etc files) in the background.

Start the stream via a link in Safari.app, and then hit the home button and the audio will continue to play.

This was very notable pre-iOS4, not sure if it worked pre iOS3 though.

Answer (score 2):

In Maps, you can switch to street view by dropping a pin, tapping it, and then tapping the little orange guy.

Comment: I tried it, but not working. The Orange guy is not highlighted when I tap the pin. (it still shows me the location)

Answer (score 2):

VoiceControl has some undocumented features:

- If you have multiple phone numbers for people, you can say which phone number to call, 'call John Smith home', 'call Davey Jones mobile'.
- If you have assigned nicknames, you can use them too 'call wife', 'call dad'

Answer (score 2):

While using the iPod/music app:

- single clicking the headphones remote
  button will pause the music.
- double clicking the headphones remote
  button will skip to the next song.
- triple clicking the headphones remote
  button will go back to the previous
  song.

Comment: Seems obvious, but it took me an embarrassingly long time to notice the latter two!

Answer (score 2):

If the iPhone is locked, and you double press the Home button to bring up the iPod controls while playing a song, shaking the iPhone skips to the next song.

Answer (score 2):

To quickly access your draft email messages, press and hold the new email button on the toolbar. A new dialog appears showing "New Message" and an option plus all of your draft emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than the 11 screen limit for apps. If you add them, they won't be displayed, but will still be installed on the phone.

You can still get to them by using a spotlight search for the app name and launch them, even though they're not visible.

*originally submitted by [Mark Struzinski](https://superuser.com/users/1546/mark-struzinski) on Super User.*

Answer (score 1):

You can remove individual text messages from a conversation by clicking the Edit button in the top right-hand corner of the Messages app.

*originally submitted by [John Topley](https://superuser.com/users/1311/john-topley) on Super User.*

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS4, while listening to music in iPod app the screen turns on for a second to show what song is currently playing. It won't happen if the iPhone is in your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two fingers to scroll through iframes and divs on web pages in Mobile Safari. One finger only scrolls the main page.

Answer (score 1):

Though this may seem obvious, little number of people know it: To switch a button's state, you just have to tap, not swipe.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 5 it's finally possible to hide the keyboard in the Messages app. Just type into the message part and pull down the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a keyboard full of emoticons, by adding the 'emoji' keyboard.

[image: Add new keyboard]

[image: Use the globe icon on the keyboard to switch to it]

Answer (score 1):

**Safari**: You can request to get the desktop for the website which automatically loads the mobile version. Simple tap and hold the reload button shown in the right corner of the address bar and an alert is shown with option to **Request Desktop Site**.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you slide your finger from right to left in a Podcast the "Delete" button appears.

*originally submitted by [Eduardo Molteni](https://superuser.com/users/717/eduardo-molteni) on Super User.*

Comment: This happens in almost any list where items can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap the status bar at the top of the screen to jump to the top of a web page or message.

*originally submitted by [Herb Caudill](https://superuser.com/users/1932/herb-caudill) on Super User.*

Answer (score 0):

Double-click home button: In settings, you can choose whether double-clicking the home button takes you to iPod controls, or to phone favorites. (If the iPod is already playing, it always takes you to iPod controls).

*originally submitted by [Herb Caudill](https://superuser.com/users/1932/herb-caudill) on Super User.*

Answer (score 0):

Safari: hit the status bar (where the time, battery etc is displayed) to scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: Works in a lot of apps too, not just Safari.  Very handy for long lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you've come around a good picture in your safari browser and sadly there's no option to save the image, you can do it via, screenshot feature in iPhone. Just hold the power button on top of iPhone and while holding it, just press Home button once. You'll get the screenshot of your iPhone screen which you can edit later easily with Photoshop Express.

http://mobile.photoshop.com/iphone/

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Or just hold your finger on the image until a save and copy button appears.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt this just last month and I can't believe I haven't known this before.

If you're going outside of your timezone and the phone is connected to the local GSM provider, it will change the clock of your phone automatically!

Comment: That's usual behaviour for modern cell phones. The last 2 or 3 phones i have been using could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Individual notifications can be actioned by sliding the app icon on the lock screen. It might be documented somewhere, but I'm surprised how few people know about this. Screenshot is of iPad, but it works the same on iPhone.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can take screenshots by pressing the **Home + Lock (Sleep)** buttons. The screenshots are added to your camera roll. After pressing the key combination, the screen flashes white for a second to notify you that it has taken a screenshot.

*originally submitted by [Blaenk](https://superuser.com/users/70/blaenk) on Super User.*

Comment: duplicate of my answer

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard tip: When you want to enter symbols, you normally tap the [.?123] key, tap your symbol or number, and then (in most cases) you have to tap the [ABC] to go back to letters.

If you only want to type one number or symbol, though, you can tap and hold the [.?123] key, drag to the number or symbol you want, then let go. You'll get the symbol and you'll immediately snap back to letter mode.

*originally submitted by [Herb Caudill](https://superuser.com/users/1932/herb-caudill) on Super User.*