# Typing umlauts and accented characters without the one second delay

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

One of the things I dislike most with the iPhone is its sized-down keyboard with only 10 keys in a row.
This may fine for English, but leaves not enough room for umlauts or accented letters.

The official way to input umlauts is to hold down the key and wait
until the umlauts and accented letters pop up, but this is way too slow.
For numbers and symbols there is the [tap-slide-release trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/undocumented-iphone-features/1719#1719),
but for umlauts this doesn't work.

Is there a way to type these letters faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Mac & i article](https://www.heise.de/mac-and-i/artikel/Das-bringt-iOS-5-Teil-1-1258302.html?artikelseite=10) iOS 5 will finally have a German keyboard with 11 keys in a row:

Edit: Only with iOS 6 this keyboard has finally [arrived](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65399/2285).

[image: Tastatur mit Ümläüten]

Yeah!

Comment: Unfortunately, this new keyboard didn't make it into the final release of iOS 5.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a direct solution to your question: Reduced delay. If your iPhone is jailbroken you might be able to find the preference file that sets the delay and reduce it.

One work around could be to not deal with the accents at all and have the iPhone insert them for you, as autocorrected words. You can now type full speed.

To add custom words to the dictionary:

- Add the Japanese Ten Key keyboard: Settings > General > Keyboards > International Keyboards > Add New Keyboard > Japanese Ten Key.
- Add words: Settings > General > Keyboards > Edit User Dictionary.
- Have the **Word** be what you want to type w/o accennts, and the **Yomi** be the accented work.

For example, I added Word=fooxx and Yomi=föoxx, I then went to the Notepad and using the English keyboard I typed "fooxx", and the iPhone suggested föoxx. When I did this example without the "xx" it did not work, perhaps because foo is already in my dictionary.

Alternatively, if you iPhone is jailbroken you could try using [Xpandr](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=12593)

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to fix the words that the keyboard learned "wrongly", or do I have to reset the dictionary?

Comment: Not sure. I'd ask this as an independent question.

Comment: @ipacheco From my experience, english auto complete and auto correction is pretty good. Portuguese is not at all and really a hateful feature. I'd like to have it turned on for english only but since I can't I just turn it off.

Comment: @mankoff: Didn't know that you can edit the user dictionary like that! I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work for me (German keyboard, iOS 4.0.1). There is another problem with all dictionary based approaches: they work for words where the spelling without the umlaut is wrong. But in German there exist many words that are valid with and without the umlaut. And in Swiss German there doesn't even exist a spelling dictionary!

Comment: You need to add the Japanese Ten Key keyboard to be able to edit the user dictionary, not German. And yes, I agree, this solution is an imperfect hack with drawbacks.

Comment: @mankoff I did add Japanese Ten Key and was able to add word pairs. I tried your exact example (fooxx/föoxx). I typed fooxx with the German, English and French keyboard in Notepad and Safari, it was never replaced by föoxx...

Comment: Strange. Works for me on iOS 4.0.1 w/ English, French, German, Greek, and Japanese 10 key in Notepad. Perhaps the first few times you type it you must manually set the accents? Perhaps if you hope it auto corrects the first time, it instead learns the non-accented way? I gotten it to work with a few words, but one time it didn't and I think that one time I didn't provide any hints for it at first...

Comment: @mankoff: It must be that it learned the uncorrected word; I found an
entry for fooxx in the German user dictionary
[de_DE-dynamic-text.dat](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2009/01/tips-to-add-words-to-iphones-dictionary.html).
But I had to go back and disable
auto-correction completely. It just doesn't work when I type English or
French words with the keyboard set to German. And changing the keyboard
everytime you write a foreign word is just plain silly...

Answer (score 1):

What umlauts are you interested in? Could you switch to a keyboard layout which has them? I use åäö which are included in the swedish keyboard layout.

Apple provides several keyboard layouts for iOS. Just go to settings, general, International, Keyboards.

Comment: This is unfair. Just installed the Swedish keyboard and noticed that it has 11 keys in a row, not ten keys like the German or French keyboard. If the swedish keyboard had the ü umlaut instead of the å it would be usable also for German...

Answer (score 0):

Worse : add the arabic keyboard, and you'll see that there's a key next to the spacebar that instantly pops up a choice of characters, when pressed.
I, too, would like that kind of behaviour for accents in French ! I hate the one second delay.

Answer (score -2):

Just want to inform everyone above that all you need to do is keep pressing the letter and all characters with signs above pop up, and there is the umlaut. I'm using 6s. Actually, just got it and needed the umlaut too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. The OP already knows how to get the umlaut, their problem is the speed at which the option pops out.

Comment: 5 years late and you apparently didn't read the question.  Recommend you delete.